# How to insert " into string of Ocaml?

Tags: string, ocaml

So I have a simple question:

I want to insert " into ocaml string, like this:

```
let a = "this is \"good\" code";;
```

But it seems that using \ is not useful

I searched for a while but could not find anything useful..

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct:

```
# let a = "this is \"good\" code";;
val a : string = "this is \"good\" code"
# String.length a;;
- : int = 19
# print_string a;;
this is "good" code- : unit = ()
#
```

Perhaps you're confused by the `\` characters in the output. The OCaml toplevel is writing the string in lexical form; i.e., in the form it should appear in an OCaml program. The `\` escapes are not part of the string, as the length and the `print_string` show.

Comment: Well, so basically it is because when I am writing some Ocaml code, I always find some errors ("Error: Syntax error") just above where I defined a string with  \  characters inside... probably the problem is not \ characters...

Comment: anyway, thank you so much, especially at the Friday late night:)

Comment: If you can reduce your syntax problem to a small example, people at SO can probably help. Glad to help at least a little.